# Using jQuery Flash in JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have a java script table that connects to a web socket and update table.
I want to use jquery falsher to flash if the value is greater than and less than the current value.

Update Table function

```
   var child = createStockNode(stock, type, template);

  // try to replace
   var stockNode = document.querySelector(type + "[data-symbol=" + stock.n + "]");
   if (stockNode) {
       table.replaceChild(child, stockNode);
   } else {
       // add new stock
       table.appendChild(child);
   }
      //stock.c ===> close Price
   var bg = stock.c < 0
           ? '255,148,148' // red
           : '154,240,117'; // green

   $row = child;
   $row.flash(bg, 1000);
   //child.flash(bg , 1000)

}
```

Jquery flusher function

```
jQuery.fn.flash = function (color, duration) {
    var current = this.css('backgroundColor');
    this.animate({ backgroundColor: 'rgb(' + color + ')' }, duration / 2)
        .animate({ backgroundColor: current }, duration / 2);
};
```

Error Uncaught ReferenceError: $row is not defined
Jquery is defined in my html page as well.

Comment: Are you sure `createStockNode` returns a jQuery object ?
Otherwise you need to do `$row = $(child)` or direclty `$(child).flash(bg, 1000)`

Comment: Where do you define $row?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
The jQuery documentation about the `animate()` function specifies :

> For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color plugin is used

---

I'd recommand to use CSS3 for thins kind of animation.
Still, here are to ways of flashing.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.blink = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
      delay: 500
    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      var obj = $(this);
      var blink = false;
      setInterval(function() {
        if (blink) {
          $(obj).css('background', options.from);
        } else {
          $(obj).css('background', options.to);
        }
        blink = !blink;
      }, options.delay);
    });
  }
}(jQuery)) 

$('#purejQuery').blink({
  delay: 500,
  from: "red",
  to: "blue"
});
```

```css
/* The animation code */
@keyframes blinking {
  0%{
    background-color: red;
  }
  50%{
    background-color: red;
  }
  51%{
    background-color: blue;
  }
  100%{
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

#pureCSS {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: blinking 1s infinite;
}

#purejQuery {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pureCSS">Done by CSS</div>

<div id="purejQuery">Done by jQuery</div>
```